# log4j2 not finding configuration file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I've developed a Dynamic Web Project using Eclypse, and I would like to use log4j2 to log infos and errors in a file.

I made the configuration file but when I start the application this error appears:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations.
```

According to the documentation, log4j2 should look for `log4j2.*` file in the WEB-INF directory, but even if the file is in there, my application still can't see it.

The file is in `.properties` format, so no additional packages should be needed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read and followed all of the instructions in the [log4j2 manual regarding web applications](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)?

Comment: Yep, but still app can't find that file. At the moment the file is inside `WEB-INF/properties` and I've added a `context-param` entry in the `web.xml` file with `param-name = log4jConfiguration` and `param-value = file:///WEB-INF/properties/log4j2.properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Logger Class  say MyLogger,   Log4j2 look for the config file location from property "log4j.configurationFile" ,  set that property in static block of the class.  this will ensure the config file location is availble to Log4j2 during startup.  You can place the config file external to the application.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import java.io.File;
public class MyLogger { 
   static {   System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile",System.getProperty("prop.loc")+File.separator+"MyLog4j2.xml");   
   }

   public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> clazz){
         return LogManager.getLogger(clazz);
   }
}
```

---

Calling class initilize logger as below

```
public class MyClass {

         private static final Logger logger = MyLogger.getLogger(MyImpl.class);

    public myMethod(){
        logger.info("My logs");
    }
}
```